# How to manipulate localStorage items when not available in the DOM

Tags: javascript

I have read a few questions on this here, but they didn't solve my question.

Take a look at this fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/aindriu80/m2xgjazn/1/

(code snippet required, full code @ jsfiddle above)

```
function increaseItem(product, cartItemDOM) {
  cart.forEach(cartItem => {
    if (cartItem.name === product.name) {
      cartItemDOM.querySelector('.cart__item__quantity').innerText = ++cartItem.quantity;
      cartItemDOM.querySelector('[data-action="DECREASE_ITEM"]').classList.remove('btn--danger');
      saveCart();
    }
  });
}
```

It's a JavaScript cart using localStorage.  It's working perfectly however I wanted to increase/decrease quantity of an item, delete an item, when I don't have access to the item in the DOM, i.e. where there is no HTML code with the item on the same webpage.

How do I change quantity or delete a specific item without manipulating the DOM ?

If I made two copies of the same HTML page and included the JavaScript(all in the fiddle) but changed the names of the items in the cart - I would have the ability to view them on another webpage but can't do anything with them (+, -, or delete).

What is the best way to do this ?

Comment: `How do I change quantity or delete a specific item without manipulating the DOM ?`, not sure what you mean here, just remove the two querySelector lines, and just do `cartItem.quantity+=1` or am I missing something?  ps. your profile say an interest in React, this seems an ideal project for React, any reason your not using it here?

Comment: hmm..im going to try that

Comment: yes, that seems to + - the item in the localStorage,

Comment: sorry, i'm just covering a piece of code for work..not spending too much time on it. 10pm here